# Display all values in the legend of a shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sp

Sample data:

```
library(raster)
fra <- getData("GADM", country = 'FRA', level = 1)
spplot(fra, "ID_1")
```

[image]

Since `ID_1` are integers, I want to display all the values in the legend as well as label the polygon with `ID_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spplot(fra, "ID_1", 
       colorkey = list(labels = list(at = fra@data$ID_1, labels = fra@data$NAME_1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. I do not want the names. I need the `D_1` values displayed in the legend but I understood how to do it now. Thanks